Sci-fi novel called the Ice Palace from the 80s
I'm trying to find a novel that I read back during the early 80s.
I thought it was called 'The Ice Palace', but I can't find any reference to it.
It is set in an 'open' prison in the arctic. The main character arrives there and has to learn how to survive in the hostile environment. There are no prison guards but the inmates have to repair cladding on the external pipes everyday, otherwise the heating will stop and they will die. That's all they have to do, day-in, day-out to survive.
Eventually the main character discovers that the prison is being run by aliens or cyborgs and a spaceship is located just out of sight of the prison. He manages to get there and then also discovers he is an alien or cyborg himself.
I can't recall the main character's name, but think one of the other characters was called 'Borg'.
Any ideas?

Any of these? The only one that looks like the right time period is the one by Robert Swindells, but from Amazon that seems to be more fantasy and doesn't have cyborgs.

Perhaps Stephen Gallagher's (written under the pen name of Stephen Couper) The Ice Belt?


Branded as a criminal by the city's upstart governors Randall is sentenced to the remote ice palace for destroying the memory bank of Command Central, the self programming computer. At first his fellow convicts in the freezing prison reject Randall, a former officer in the elite police. But their suspicions melt when Randall discovers the alien shuttle and its strange crew. From the safety of their giant mother-ship the aliens are bleeding Persephone white. They keep their distance, but their servants from the shuttle walk the planet and work in league with traitors in the city. They move unrecognised, they are trusted, they are even loved. And even they do not know if they are robots or humans.

It's part of a trilogy that started with Dying of Paradise and ended with The Babylon Run.
Found with a search for site:goodreads.com prison "ice palace"
The Internet Archive does not seem to have the book to borrow, but they do have three serials based on the novels.

I wish I could upvote multiple times for taking the time to identify the search you used to find the solution. You didn't just give someone a fish, you taught them how to fish. Fabulous!

Can I ask where you did that search.
I had searched using Google and ChatGPT and only gt results for
"The Ice Palace" by Tarjei Vesaas
I've just done the same search and got the same results. No mention of "The Ice Belt"

@RetroVibe: I used Google. It's about the fourth search result for me, including in Incognito mode. You narrowed it down to Goodreads? That's a trick I often use for books, because "book" is far too broad and not everyone uses "novel" to describe their book.
